# Phonegap (jQuery mobile, JS) : get several xml files in a folder

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-mobile

I can do Ajax for one specific file :

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: url,
    dataType:"xml",
    success: function(data) {   
    }
});
```

But I'd like to do it will all xml files in my folder. It's impossible to list filenames in a folder with javascript. I read, after, than PHP can open all xml files and wrap these files in a JSON object. Then I'll just have to getJSON from my mobile app.
For information, all xml files have the same structure.

Anyone for PHP help. I tried to create an exemple :

```
<?php
for($var=5; $var<10; $var++){
    $myArray[]=$var;
}
echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

But I can't even get the array :/